# Android SearchView: styling suggestions list

Tags: android, android-styles, android-search

I have problems to style the suggestions list from a ActionBar SearchView (support v7).

Which style attribute I have to style to change the background and text color?

Ralph

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    // Theme the SearchView's AutoCompleteTextView drop down. For some reason this wasn't working in styles.xml
    SearchAutoComplete autoCompleteTextView = (SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);

    if (autoCompleteTextView != null) { 
        autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc_search_dropdown_light);
    }
}
```

Comment: This can change the background of the list only. How about the row of the suggestion list?